# Why is higher order unification in Scala considered partial?

Tags: scala, type-inference, terminology, type-constructor

[SI-2712 Add support for partial unification of type constructors #5102](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/5102) initially provided the feature under flag

```sh
-Yhigher-order-unification
```

but then renamed it to

```sh
-Ypartial-unification
```

because it seems not to be full higher order unification according to

[comment](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/5102#issuecomment-219803596)

> "partial type application inference" is probably a better term for
> what's happening here than "higher-order unification", which this most
> certainly is not

[comment 2](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/5102#issuecomment-219885683)

> rename it to `-Ypartial-unification` to reflect that fact it doesn't
> implement a general HOU algorithm.

How is partial unification different from higher order unification? In what sense does Scala not implement higher order unification? Could you demonstrate with a concrete code snippet when Scala is not able to perform HOU?

Comment: First of all, names are genrally opinion based. About this particular naming decision, I think its more about the approach and less about the direct and in-direct effects. Here the approach clearly uses a local type alias which partially applies the actual type constructor.

Comment: Voted for closure because it's not a reproducible problem. I recommend asking this on other platforms such as official chat

Answer (score 3):

Broadly, the Scala implementation will only perform higher-order unification if the "missing" type is the right-most type.

[Daniel Spiewak](https://gist.github.com/djspiewak/7a81a395c461fd3a09a6941d4cd040f2) demonstrates this with a functor instance for a type that's basically `Either`, but left biased.